# Flash: gradient fill disappears when it's drawn outside the bounds of its parent?

Tags: flash, gradient

I'm trying to draw a gradient in Flash using `beginGradientFill` and `drawRect`, but when the rect being drawn is partially outside the bounds of the parent, the gradient isn't drawn at all.

For example, consider the code below:

```
function testGradient():void {
    var g:Graphics = container.graphics;
    var width:Number = container.width;
    var height:Number = container.height;
    var y:Number = 0;
    var x:Number = 0;
    var ratios:Array = [255 * y / height, 255 * (y + height) / height];
    g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xFF, 0xFF], [0.6, 0], 
                        ratios, null);
    g.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
    g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    g.endFill(); 
}
```

When the rectangle being drawn lies within the bounds of `container`, everything works:

[image: working gradient]

However, if the rectangle lies outside of the bounds of the container, the gradient isn't drawn at all. For example, if the code is changed to:

```
...
var x:Number = 10;
var y:Number = 10;
...
```

Then the gradient disappears:

[image: broken gradient]

Short of doing the math required to draw the box inside the bounds of the parent (and fixing up the gradient so it looks correct), is there any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using the x/y positions in your ratio calculations, and that can lead to out-of-bounds values.

using your ratio calc, when x/y are both zero, then you get a nice smooth gradient:

`ratios = [0,255]`

however, when you, for instance, set x/y to 10, your ratios array becomes

`ratios = [25.5,280.5]`

which is invalid. `ratios` needs to be a linear series of integers from 0-255. Exceeding the bounds cause the variable to be ignored.

Either hardcode your `ratios` var if you want consistant gradients for you box regardless of its x/y position, or do some bounds checking on the values you enter in the ratio array to make sure they are between 0-255.

keep in mind, that when calling `drawRect` on a graphics object, the x/y/width/height are relative to the object whose `graphics` object you are manipulating.

hope that helps.